# Python HTTPServer: How to convert the extracted post data to python dictionary

Tags: python, http, https

Hey so I have a simple basic python HTTPServer ,now from the post request I have sent in some data now when I extract the data I get the following out below exactly as is:

```
b'{"name":"john",  "lastname":"Doe"}'
```

**This is how I am extracting the given data:**

```
content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
print(post_body)
```

**Is the a way of converting the output to a proper dictionary?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(b'{"name":"john",  "lastname":"Doe"}'.decode("utf-8"))
```

`literal_eval` evaluates strings into the pythonic equivalent of their content. The `decode` is needed in order to turn `bytes` into `str`.